# Preencher vetor e verificar se valor da posição atual é igual a anterior

Tags: javascript, lógica, while

```
btnInnerText(btns[0],sorteio());
var bool = true;
for(var i=1;i<btns.length;i++){
    do{
        btnInnerText(btns[i],sorteio());
        for(var j=0;j<btns.length;j++){
            if(getValorBTN(i)==getValorBTN(j))
                bool=false;             
            else
                bool=true;

        }
    }while(bool==true)

}

for(var i=0;i<btns.length;i++){
    console.log("Posição = "+i+" - Valor = "+getValorBTN(i));
}
```

**O problema é que sempre gera alguns números repetidos. E o que eu quero é que randomize números aleatórios sem repetir nenhum valor no vetor**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A função sorteio é pra sortear um número entre 1 e 10 e a função `getValorBTN` é pra pegar os valores dos botes HTML

```
function getValorBTN(posicaoBTN){
    var valor=parseInt(document.getElementById(btns[posicaoBTN]).textContent);
    return valor;
}
```

Outra coisa que não tô entendendo muito bem é que se eu colocar a condição `while(bool==false)` fica em `loop` infinito. Certamente tô confundindo as coisas, mas eu acho que era pra repetir quando `bool=false` e sair quando for o contrário.

Comment: Se getValorBTN é uma função, por que você está usando colchetes pra acessar? `getValorBTN[i]==getValorBTN[j]`

Comment: Outra coisa, voce explicou o problema mas não explicou o que quer fazer. Não disse qual é o objetivo disso tudo. **Parece** que você quer gerar um vetor com números aleatórios sem repetição.

Comment: Corrigido, mas agora fica em loop infinito

Comment: É exatamente isso mesmo que eu quero, eu atualizei o post

Comment: Como falei, depois da correção, tá em loop infinito. Coloquei dois console.log distintos pra verificar se entrava no if ou else, e tava verificando. Porém mesmo assim não saía do loop, somente colocando o break no else. E mesmo com o break, ainda repete alguns números no vetor

Comment: O que essa condição significa `getValorBTN(i)==getValorBTN(j)`? Qual a intenção por trás dela?

Comment: Verificar em todas as posições se há um valor igual. No caso, como i começa em 1, o segundo for(var j=0;j<btns.length;j++) vai percorrer todos os botões HTML, pegar o valor deles (getValorBTN) e verificar. Coloquei dentro de do..while pra refazer o sorteio sem repetir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> eu quero é que randomize números aleatórios sem repetir nenhum valor no vetor

Primeiro, vamos criar uma função que retorna um número aleatório dentro de um intervalo específico.

```
function obterNumeroAleatorio(minimo, maximo) {
  return minimo + Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximo - minimo + 1));
}
```

Agora, vamos criar uma função que acumula N números aleatórios dentro de um intervalo específico.

```
function gerarNumerosSemRepeticao(quantidadeNumeros, minimo, maximo) {
  const numerosSemRepeticao = new Set();

  while (numerosSemRepeticao.size < quantidadeNumeros) {
    const numeroAleatorio = obterNumeroAleatorio(minimo, maximo);
    numerosSemRepeticao.add(numeroAleatorio);
  }

  return [...numerosSemRepeticao];
}
```

Portanto, para gerar 10 números aleatórios entre 1 e 100, basta chamar

```
const numeros = gerarNumerosSemRepeticao(10, 1, 100);
console.log(numeros);
```

- Caso não saiba o que é `Set`, [clique aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).
- Caso não saiba o que é `[...x]`, [clique aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

---

Se quiser usar somente arrays, basta você fazer um laço `for` que compara o número sorteado com cada um dos números já selecionados.

```
function gerarNumerosSemRepeticao(quantidadeNumeros, minimo, maximo) {
  const numerosSelecionados = [];

  while (numerosSelecionados.length < quantidadeNumeros) {
    const numeroSorteado = obterNumeroAleatorio(minimo, maximo);
    let encontrouIgual = false;

    for (const numero of numerosSelecionados) {
      if (numero === numeroSorteado) {
        encontrouIgual = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!encontrouIgual) {
      numerosSelecionados.push(numeroSorteado);
    }
  }

  return numerosSelecionados;
}
```

Mas tenha em mente que isso piora muito o tempo de execução da função. Usando `Set` ela é `O(n)`, usando array ela se torna `O(n^2)`. Se não souber o que isso significa, [clique aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande-O).

---

Apenas a título de curiosidade, saiba que você também pode criar um array de números sequenciais e misturá-lo aleatoriamente. O resultado final será o mesmo (considerando que o intervalo de números aleatórios compreenda todos os números no vetor).

Para misturar os elementos de um vetor usa-se o algoritmo de embaralhamento do Knuth (se não souber o que é, [clique aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)).

```
function misturarElementos(vetor) {
  function inverter(i, j) {
    const temp = vetor[i];
    vetor[i] = vetor[j];
    vetor[j] = temp;
  }

  for (let i = vetor.length - 1; i; i--) {
    let j = obterNumeroAleatorio(0, i);
    inverter(i, j);
  }
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
const numeros = [];

// Preencher o vetor com números sequenciais
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  numeros.push(i);
}

// Usar o Knuth shuffle para embaralhar os elementos no vetor
misturarElementos(numeros);

// Agora os elementos parecem aleatórios!
console.log(numeros);
```

Este algoritmo é `O(n)`.

Comment: Realmente funciona do seu método. Queria saber, é se existe uma forma de ir preenchendo qualquer que seja o vetor e ir verificando se há valores iguais no mesmo, usando laço de repetições. Eu quero saber pra fins de conhecimento, afinal minha lógica estava confusa, queria corrigir isso, só a resposta pronta não faz sentido pro meu aprendizado... Grato!

Comment: @Henrique Editei a resposta pra mostrar a lógica usando apenas arrays, mas note que o algoritmo se torna muito menos eficiente.

Comment: @Henrique Adicionei mais uma forma de fazer o que você quer. Uma abordagem bem diferente.

Comment: Bem interessante, nessas horas que uma faculdade de CC faz falta, principalmente pra mim que sou cismado com bibliotecas/funções prontas. Só uso estes meios pra produzir mais rápido, porém o que gosto mesmo é de aprender o que acontece por trás ao máximo. Obrigado pelas respostas